# random data generator to use with load tests in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, load-testing

I am new to Ruby and I want to load test my application written using Ruby on Rails frame and I need a tool/gem/library to generate random unique data to use it for the load testing since some functions such as user creation require unique data. Can you suggest a tool for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two gems used for creating objects in test setup with Ruby/Rails:

Factory Bot: This gem allows you to create instances of your active record models and instantiate them in your test setup in reproducible way:
https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot_rails

Faker: Good for generating random bits of information, such as names, email addresses, phone numbers, text blobs, when 'foo bar' doesn't quite cut it:
https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker

Reading into these two should give you a start!